# How does Apple keychain retrieve passwords without asking for master key?

Tags: macos, encryption, password-encryption

OSX and iOS store all your passwords in the Keychain App. If you open the Keychain and want to see any password you are asked for "master password".

However I noriced that if you visit a website on Safari that requires the same password to login, it just fills in the password without asking you for the master pass. If the passwords are encrypted how could it be able to retrieve them without your key? Are they unencrypted? In such case what's the poijt of asking me for the password when I want to see them?

Comment: Have you read the [Keychain Services Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/01introduction/introduction.html)?

Comment: While the keychain is unlocked then your unlock password (or some version of it) is stored in memory so trusted applications can retrieve passwords. Asking for a password again when you want to see it is a security measure. Although a person could potentially log-in into a web page while your keychain is unlocked, they will not be able to get your password.

Comment: but can't somebody get hold of that unlocked password? It's not true that you can log-in into a web page but not get the password in question. I can easily inspect retrieve the password once it's autocompleted with some js for Gmail: document.getElementById("Passwd").value;